# Border Layout looping. JPanel/swing

Tags: java, swing, loops, jpanel, border-layout

I'm having trouble with my looping and 'BorderLayout'. When I compile and run this using the driver it seems that the add.west(etc) is being overwritten by the proceeding add.west. I am left only with the 9th component in the 'south' panel, with 'east' and 'west' being completely empty. If I change the "for (int i=0; i<8; i++){" to: "for (int i=0; i<2; i++){" I get ONLY the second element of the required 9 in the 'west' panel. Can anyone please tell me why. Forgive my ignorance. I'm a beginner.

Thankyou.
Joe

This is roughly what it should look like:

```
(WEST)                                           (EAST)

btn0, label0, label0                            btn4, label4, label4
btn1, label1, label1                            btn5, label5, label5
btn2, label2, label2                            btn6, label6, label6
btn3, label3, label3                            btn7, label7, label7

                           (SOUTH)
                    btn8, label8, label8
```

//CODE STARTS HERE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class CoinPanel extends JPanel{
  private JButton buttons[] = new JButton[9];
  private JLabel multiplySign[] = new JLabel[9];
  private JLabel coinCount[] = new JLabel[9];
  String [] names= {"1c", "2c", "5c", "10c", "20c", "50c", "€1", "€2", "Reset"};
  int [] values= {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 0};

  public CoinPanel(){
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
      buttons[i] = new JButton(names[i]);
      buttons[i].addActionListener(new BtnListener());
      coinCount[i] = new JLabel("0", JLabel.CENTER);
      coinCount[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
      multiplySign[i] = new JLabel ("x", JLabel.CENTER);
```

//Layout stuff from here:

```
      setLayout (new BorderLayout());
      JPanel west= new JPanel();
      west.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      JPanel east= new JPanel();
      east.setBackground(Color.RED);
      JPanel south= new JPanel();
      south.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

      if(i<4){
        west.add (buttons[i]);
        west.add (multiplySign[i]);
        west.add (coinCount[i]);
      }
      else if(i<8){
        east.add (buttons[i]);
        east.add (multiplySign[i]);
        east.add (coinCount[i]);
      } 
      else{
        multiplySign[i].setText("TOTAL");
        south.add (multiplySign[i]);
        south.add (coinCount[i]);
        south.add (buttons[i]);
      }
      add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);     
      add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     }

    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(450,300));
  }
```

//To here^^^

```
private class BtnListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
      String [] text = new String[9];
      int [] intArray = new int [9];
      double sum =0;
      for (int i=0; i<(intArray.length-1); i++){
        if(event.getSource() == buttons[i]){
          text[i] = coinCount[i].getText();
          intArray[i]=Integer.parseInt(text[i]);
          intArray[i] = ((intArray[i]) +1);
          coinCount[i].setText(intArray[i] + "");
       }    
       if(event.getSource() == buttons[8]){
         coinCount[i].setText("0");
       }
       sum += (Integer.parseInt(coinCount[i].getText())*values[i]);
       NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
       coinCount[8].setText(nf.format(sum/100)+"");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

//AND THIS IS THE DRIVER:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class CoinSorter{
   public static void main(String[] args){ 
      JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Coin Counter Example");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      CoinPanel panel = new CoinPanel();
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Only a single component can be added to a specific location in a BorderLayout. So you can only have 5 components. Of course you can always add a JPanel to any location which can contain as many components as you want.

Comment: For better help sooner, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: "Only a single component can be added to a specific location in a BorderLayout"... Am I not only adding a single Panel to the three locations?

Comment: Also dont call `setPreferredSize(..)` rather override `getPreferredSize()` but only when you are drawing to `Graphics` object of `JComponent`, other than that use correct `LayoutManager` and call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible but after adding components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I not only adding a single Panel to the three locations?

No, you have too much code in your loop.

1) You are creating 3 new panels every time you execute the loop.

- the creation of your 3 west, east and south panels should be done before the loop starts.

2) Then at the end of the loop you are adding each of these panels to your main panel.

- the three panels should be added to the main panel outside of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can only have 1 component at which location at a time.
By adding another component to the same location (e.g. BorderLayout.WEST), you remove previous one. This is code from BorderLayout class that clearly shows that every time you add a WEST component, member variable `west` gets new value and old one is lost:

```
if ("Center".equals(name)) {
    center = comp;
} else if ("North".equals(name)) {
    north = comp;
} else if ("South".equals(name)) {
    south = comp;
} else if ("East".equals(name)) {
    east = comp;
} else if ("West".equals(name)) {
    west = comp;
} else if (BEFORE_FIRST_LINE.equals(name)) {
    firstLine = comp;
} else if (AFTER_LAST_LINE.equals(name)) {
    lastLine = comp;
} else if (BEFORE_LINE_BEGINS.equals(name)) {
    firstItem = comp;
} else if (AFTER_LINE_ENDS.equals(name)) {
    lastItem = comp;
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot add to layout: unknown constraint: " + name);
}
  }
}
```

Same goes for other placements.

Comment: Actually they are not removed. They get piled up. The component remains in its parent container and keeps that last bounds that have been set by the LayoutManager. This usually results in flickering and many issues with MouseEvent's

Comment: @Guillaume Polet, they are removed from layout and never flicker. You probably had a different problem. Components are kept in the container's children list, but they are removed from LayoutManager and thus never painted.

Comment: Actually, in most case all children will get painted, even if they overlap each other. You can only expect weird results in those cases.

Comment: -1, @ATrubka, components are NOT removed. If you add multiple components at design time the size of each component is (0, 0). When the layout manager is invoked only the last component added is resized. So it looks like only the last component is painted. However, if you add another component once the frame is visible, then the layout manager will resize this component, but now you have two components with sizes so you will get unexpected results (ie. the previous component is painted over top of the last component added).